# swiftui: how to conditionally replace a CommandGroup?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm using SwiftUI for my macOS app, and running into trouble trying to change the File menu depending on whether the user has purchased an upgrade.

I've got this:

```
.commands {
   CommandGroup(after: .newItem) {
       ExamplesMenu(name: "Open Example")
   }
   etc.
}
```

I want to disable the "New" command if the user hasn't purchased an upgrade, so that would be something like:

```
            if didPurchase {
                CommandGroup(after: .newItem) {
                    ExamplesMenu(name: "Open Example")
                }
            } else {
                CommandGroup(replacing: .newItem) {
                    ExamplesMenu(name: "Open Example")
                }
            }
```

However that yields the error:

`Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder 'CommandsBuilder'`

Is there a way of accomplishing this without ditching SwiftUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try this:

```
.commands {
    didPurchase 
      ? CommandGroup(after: .newItem) { ExamplesMenu(name: "Open Example") }
      : CommandGroup(replacing: .newItem) { ExamplesMenu(name: "Open Example") }
}
```